# microsoft azure sdk 2.9 fails to install

Tags: azure, failed-installation, web-platform-installer

Microsoft Azure sdk 2.9 fails to install from the Web Platform Installer 5.0

[Original Post, consider skipping to the edited post]
Picture showing the error (can't post it as an image cuz it's my first post and it says I need 10 reputation):
dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18135227/TempLinks/AzureSDK2.9Fails.png
The log files that the failing installation prompts me to read, are:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18135227/TempLinks/TempLinks.zip
I've gone ahead and uninstall everything azure related, restarted and tried to install it again
I've also tried solutions offered in similar threads here, like the one saying to delete the XML files from the Web Platform Installer 5.0 and try the installation again
Nothing worked so far...
Thanks to anyone who can figure this out and actually reply to help :)

[Edit: New post]
I've tried all the suggestion so far but couldn't get it to work.

I have a more detailed file now here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18135227/TempLinks/Microsoft-Azure-SDK-for-.NET-%28VS-2015%29---2.9_Logs.rar

The numbered pictures (1-5) show how i got from VS's Update Extensions dialogue to updating the Azure SDK and finally to failing performing the update.

In the last picture there are 6 Log Files mentioned on the window.

All files are numbered (6-11) in the respective order they appear on the last picture.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might have tried this but just to make sure...

1. Go to Control Panel>Programs & Features and search for "Azure PowerShell" - uninstall everything you find.
2. Take a look at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell and make sure the folder is empty
3. Go back to the Web Platform Installer and try to reinstall (the link Alex posted should be fine).

If that doesn't work, email me and we'll try to debug (bmoore at microsoft.com)

(Note: the Azure Stack Tech Preview for PowerShell (or a later version) is required for the SDK to install)

Comment: I've tried all the suggestion - couldn't get it to work.
I have a more detailed file now here: [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18135227/TempLinks/Microsoft-Azure-SDK-for-.NET-%28VS-2015%29---2.9_Logs.rar)

The numbered pictures (1-5) show how i got from VS's Update Extensions dialogue to updating the Azure SDK and finally to failing performing the update.
In the last picture there are 6 Log Files mentioned on the window. all files are numbered (6-11) in the respective ordered they appear on the last picture.

bmoore-msft and @Alex-Belotserkovskiy thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

please try to install it using the [Web Platform Installer](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=746481) shortcut.
From your screenshot i see that you are trying to install some Azure Stack related products which are not necessary for Azure SDK. Shortcut allows to install only needed prerequisites.

I took a look at your logs and could not find the issue. But i had the same errors, and the solution was to find leftovers. In my case, it was:
c:\user:

```
WAStorageEmulatorDb...mdf
WAStorageEmulatorDb..._log.ldf
```

Change the locations of these files (if they are there) or delete. I was able to install the SDK with the help of that.

Comment: Thank you both for your inputs.
I shall try your suggestions and head back here to share the results (whether a success or not).

Unfortunately it's 5:36AM here in greece and i've been working for the bloody M.Sc projects non stop all day (and night.. and midnight apparently)
As soon as I get 10 minutes to try I'll do so and reply here.
Again - thank you both